# Why don't I see all variables in debugger?

Tags: java, collections, set, treemap, treeset

[image: Intellij IDEA debugger]

Hi all!

I tried to debug `TreeSet<String>`/`TreeMap<String>` but found that debugger for some reason doesn't want to show me `parent` and `left`/`right` children of the nodes.

I expected to see nested nodes but only key/values are exposed.
Of course, if I evaluate `this.left`/`this.right` it will give me the child.

Is it IDEA bug? Why does it show only key and value?

Also, I noticed that when we get elements from client code we receive `String` instead of `TreeMap.Entry`. What should we do in order to get a `parent`/`left`/`right` of the current item in client code?

Comment: "What should we do in order to get a parent/left/right of the current item in client code?"  This is _very deliberately_ not possible, to preserve flexibility in the implementation.

Comment: This is how the code was compiled. Some local slots don't have debug information. It has inferred that slot 3 is `t` so you can see everything.

Answer (score 3):

You’re using a `TreeMap` so you have key/values and it’s sorted by keys as if all the keys were in a `TreeSet` and a `TreeSet` does not refer to a binary tree with *parent / left / rigth* like

```
   parent
     |
   node
  /    \
left  right
```

A `TreeSet` is an `ordered set` following rules as `natural order` or a `custom comparator`

---

> [TreeSet Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) : A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

So a `TreeMap` is a `TreeSet` where you just add a value to each key

Comment: But all nodes are of TreeMap.Entry type

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs have an option to display a collection's contents in a more "friendly" way instead of displaying the collection's internal data structures. It's probably this way because most programmers are *using* collections but not *debugging* them, and therefore seeing the collection's internal structures obscures the collection's contents.

In the NetBeans, this option can be changed by going to Preferences in the Java > Java Debugger category, and setting various "formatters" such as those for Collection, Map, and Map.Entry.

In IntelliJ IDEA, bring up the Settings dialog, and look under Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java. The option is called "Enable alternative view for Collections classes." (Thanks, Matt Leidholm!)

As to the second part of your question, if you're using a `TreeMap<K, V>` the API exposes only the types `K` and `V` that you're using. The `TreeMap.Entry` structure is an internal data structure that's kept private from the client. The client can't navigate the tree structure (left/right/parent) itself. The intent of `TreeMap` is not to expose a tree structure, but to provide an *abstraction* of a map whose keys and values are exposed, sorted by key.

You can get `Map.Entry` references by calling `entrySet()`. These are references to actual `TreeMap.Entry` objects. However, the `Map.Entry` doesn't expose left/right/parent; it only exposes keys and values.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, the preference you are talking about is in the Settings dialog, under Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java. It is called "Enable alternative view for Collections classes".

Comment: @MattLeidholm Thank you! I figured IDEA would have something equivalent.